# vue-tables-2 event emit not registering for custom filter

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-tables-2

I'm getting this error: "TypeError: Event.$emit is not a function" whenever the watcher fires.

I can console log the Event object since I imported it in my main.js file.
I use a named prop because I have 3 different client tables on 1 page. I named the table as rmTable

```
<v-client-table name="rmTable" :data="filteredRMInvData" :columns="rmColumns" :options="rmOptions" v-if="rmInventoryData.length">
```

In my watcher:

```
materialType(value) {
    Event.$emit('vue-tables.rmTable.filter::materialtype', value)
}
```

This is my customFilters in my rmOptions variable:

```
customFilters: [{ 
    name: 'materialtype', 
    callback(row, query) {
        console.log(row)
        console.log(query)
        return query.code.includes(row.material_group)
    }
}],
```

How can I do this correctly? At least I should be able to see the row and query logs. I checked the guide on [the github page](https://github.com/matfish2/vue-tables-2#events) and it seems I followed it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have

```
Vue.use(VueTables.Event);
```

Then

```
materialType(value) {
    VueTables.Event.$emit('vue-tables.rmTable.filter::materialtype', value)
}
```

`Event` is already a browser interface, which I'm guess is the reason it doesn't work.